# python 2.7 create dictionary key from tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

How do I create an ordered dictionary key from a tuple in Python 2.7?

I have seen a lot of examples about creating a new dictionary from a tuple, or building tuples from dictionary keys but not how to generate a "multi-dimensional key" from a tuple, i.e. use the keys in the tuple to recursively index into a nested dictionary.

Basically I would like to use a tuple such as:

```
('australia', 'queensland', 'brisbane')
```

as a dictionary key:

```
places['australia']['queensland']['brisbane']
```

The dictionary is an OrderedDict that contains JSON data.

Comment: Do you mean that `places` is a dict of dicts of dicts?

Comment: It's not a very hard problem in general, though what is the value?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please refer to: [ask].  Please post a [mcve].  You also didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour before asking

Answer (score 1):

One liner (where `t` is your tuple and `places` is your dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries of...):

```
reduce(dict.get, t, places)
```

What's actually happening here is that you're repeatedly `get`ting each element of the tuple `t` from the dict `places`.

In python 3, you'll need to import reduce via `from functools import reduce`.